# Notifications are being sent to guests randomly when event is created/updated with Google Calendar V3 API

Tags: notifications, google-calendar-api

Calendar notifications are sent out to attendees though the send_notification parameter is false in the API (default is false). But this is happening randomly, not for every user calendar that our app was creating event using insert/update API.

We are not sure if this is an issue on Google side. As we are seeing it randomly it has become very difficult for us to troubleshoot. Appreciate any help from Google.

Attendees in the event could be Google hosted domain users or MS Exchange users. Every one is getting invitation.

Thanks in advance.
durga

Comment: What exactly is your question? What have you tried?

Comment: We have an application that creates or updates calender events in Google calendar using V3 API. We are using google-api-python client for creating/updating events. As per my knowledge default settings for sending notifcation is false. Our customers are reporting that they are seeing calendar invitations when an event is created/updated from our application. However attendees are recieving invitations for random events. We are not sure for which scenarios these invitations are beign sent out to guests.